# how to add, element from a button react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

[image: picture of app]

how to add, element from a button react native,
I want to create a project as seen in the image, but I don't know how to add an element from a button, add a div with two inputs and when saving start from the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can use an array as your state. And every time you can push your view in the array (when the user clicks plus in your example).

```
const SampleView = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
      <TextInput style={{ width: 200, height: 40, margin: 10 }} label="placeholder" />
      <TextInput style={{ width: 200, height: 40, margin: 10 }} label="placeholder" />
    </View>
  );
};

......
........


const [views, setViews] = React.useState([]);

const addItems = () => {
    const arr = [...views];
    arr.push(<SampleView />);

    setViews(arr);
  };
```

Finally, you can render the array items.

```
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {views.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <View style={{ padding: 10}}>
            <Text>item : {index}</Text>
            {item}
          </View>
        );
      })}
      <Button onPress={addItems}>
        <Text>Add</Text>
      </Button>
    </View>
```

Here is a snack link for you to get the full idea. https://snack.expo.io/@saad-bashar/dynamic-elements